# How to replace any NULL values with an integer that might or could appear in the Foreign key columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I run the script, The 5 foreign keys such as ResourceKey, AusFunctionKey, IntFunctionKey,  RegionViewKey and EntityKey from 5 dimension tables always have values. Because I set the 5  primary keys data type in each dimension tables as INT. However, when I link all dimensions into a fact table, there are "some" foreign keys that have NULL values.

How do I put a case when statement or anything that I could add to replace any NULL values with an integer such as "1"??

```
SELECT d.resourcekey, 
       CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dw, Getdate()), 
                                        Getdate() 
                                        ), 112)) AS TimeKey, 
       A.ausfunctionkey, 
       I.intfunctionkey, 
       o.regionviewkey, 
       E.entitykey                               AS EmployingEntityKey, 
       r.resourceid, 
       r.subsubfunctioncode, 
       r.sublocationcode, 
       r.site, 
       t.sitedesc, 
       Sum(t.itemvalue1)                         AS HoursOutstanding, 
       Sum(t.itemvalue1 * Isnull(CASE 
                                   WHEN t.itemvalue2 = 0 THEN r.costrateregoper 
                                   ELSE r.costrateintoper 
                                 END, 0))        AS OperCostOutstanding, 
       Sum(t.itemvalue1 * Isnull(CASE 
                                   WHEN t.itemvalue2 = 0 THEN 
                                   r.chargerateregoper 
                                   ELSE r.chargerateintoper 
                                 END, 0))        AS OperRevenueOutstanding, 
   Sum(t.itemvalue1 * Isnull(CASE 
                               WHEN t.itemvalue2 = 0 THEN r.costratereghome 
                               ELSE r.costrateinthome 
                             END, 0))        AS HomeCostOutstanding, 
       Sum(t.itemvalue1 * Isnull(CASE 
                                   WHEN t.itemvalue2 = 0 THEN 
                                   r.chargeratereghome 
                                   ELSE r.chargerateinthome 
                                 END, 0))        AS HomeRevenueOutstanding, 
       r.homecurrcode, 
       Sum(t.itemvalue1 * Isnull(CASE 
                                   WHEN t.itemvalue2 = 0 THEN r.costrateregnat 
                                   ELSE r.costrateintnat 
                                 END, 0))        AS NatCostOutstanding, 
       Sum(t.itemvalue1 * Isnull(CASE 
                                   WHEN t.itemvalue2 = 0 THEN r.chargerateregnat 
                                   ELSE r.chargerateintnat 
                                 END, 0))        AS NatRevenueOutstanding, 
       r.natcurrcode 
FROM   ods_currentresource r 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ods_staff_task t 
                    ON R.resourceid = T.resourceid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dwresourcetask.dbo.dimresource D 
                    ON T.resourceid = D.resourceid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dwresourcetask.dbo.dimaustralianfunction A 
                    ON R.subsubfunctioncode = A.subsubfunctioncode 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dwresourcetask.dbo.diminternationalfunction I 
                    ON R.subsubfunctioncode = I.subsubfunctioncode 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dwresourcetask.dbo.dimregion o 
                    ON R.sublocationcode = o.sublocationcode 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dwresourcetask.dbo.dimentity E 
                    ON R.legalentity = E.entcode 
WHERE  r.resourcetypecode <> 'C' 
       AND t.sitedesc = r.resourcesite 
       AND t.tasktypeid IN ( 5, 6 ) --missing time 
GROUP  BY d.resourcekey, 
          A.ausfunctionkey, 
          I.intfunctionkey, 
          o.regionviewkey, 
          E.entitykey, 
          r.resourceid, 
          r.subsubfunctioncode, 
          r.sublocationcode, 
          r.site, 
          t.sitedesc, 
          t.resourceid, 
          r.homecurrcode, 
          r.natcurrcode
```

Comment: `COALESCE(some_column, 1234) as the_column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ISNULL(A.ausfunctionkey, 1) as ausfunctionkey`  when querying. This will give you the appopriate value or if it is NULL, then the output will be 1

Comment: This also worked on my script.

case when A.AusFunctionKey is NULL then 1 else A.AusFunctionKey end as AusFunctionKey,

Comment: Case can be used for more complex checking operations. In your case ISNULL is better in terms of performance too

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE
    WHEN [myRow] IS NULL THEN 1234
END
```

Or (as somebody else said) use [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)
Example:

```
SELECT Description, ISNULL(MaxQty, 0.00) AS 'Max Quantity' FROM Sales.SpecialOffer;
```

Comment: If this is what you meant then it didn't work

***case when o.RegionViewKey is NULL then 1 end as RegionViewKey,***